# php vfsStream is not parsing newline characters

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, vfs-stream

I'm trying to unit test methods in isolation that work with csv files, using vsf-stream from here: https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream

I've created a 2 dimensional data array to test, but when I try to add this to the mocked file it seems to parse the newline characters, instead of adding new lines. I've tried both `fputcsv` and `fputs` but both have the same results. Using the same data and php functions I can write successfully to a normal file, the issues seems to be with vfs-stream. Not much documentation on the net and completely lost:

```
$this->data = array(
    array( 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4' ),
    array( 'row 0 1', 'row 0 2', ' row 0 3', ' row 0 4' ),
    array( 'row 1 1', 'row 1 2', ' row 1 3', ' row 1 4' ),
    array( 'row 2 1', 'row 2 2', ' row 2 3', ' row 2 4' ),
    array( 'row 3 1', 'row 3 2', ' row 3 3', ' row 3 4' ),
    array( 'row 4 1', 'row 4 2', ' row 4 3', ' row 4 4' ),
    array( 'row 5 1', 'row 5 2', ' row 5 3', ' row 5 4' ),
);
$this->root = vfsStream::setup('test-dir');
$file = vfsStream::url('test-dir/foo.csv');
    $handle = fopen($file, "a+");
foreach( $this->data as $arr)
    fputcsv($handle, $arr, "|"); //$content .= implode("|", $arr) . "\n";
```

The above code will produce the mocked file but without any newline characters, so parsing the mocked csv file later in the test won't work as it seems to all be written in the one long line:

```
var_dump( file_get_contents( $file ) );
```

will produce:

```
string(272) "col1|col2|col3|col4\n"row 0 1"|"row 0 2"|" row 0 3"|" row 0 4"\n"row 1 1"|"row 1 2"|" row 1 3"|" row 1 4"\n"row 2 1"|"row 2 2"|" row 2 3"|" row 2 4"\n"row 3 1"|"row 3 2"|" row 3 3"|" row 3 4"\n"row 4 1"|"row 4 2"|" row 4 3"|" row 4 4"\n"row 5 1"|"row 5 2"|" row 5 3"|" row 5 4"\n"
```

I'm hoping that I'm missing a flag for this and its not a bug. Any help appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using `var_dump` instead of `print` or `echo` to see the results. `var_dump` will give a descriptive and literal representation of the variable and not parse the `\n` chars - `print` or `echo` would print and parse the `\n` chars.

Therefore the above code works and its my stupidity or lack of sleep that is the issue.